# How would I go about designing this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

Basically; I am on the Announcements page of a Client Control Panel, and I need to show the First Name of whoever made that announcement.  I have their contact ID.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcements ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;") or log_e();
/* Returns:
   Array {
     ['id'] = 1
     ['poster_id'] = 1
     ['when'] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     ['title'] = "Example Announcement"
     ['message'] = "..."
   }
*/
```

An excerpt from the UML design document is as follows:
[image: UML Design Document]

I have the "poster", which relates to the "id" in "users"...  The "main_contact" from "users" relates to the "id" in contacts.  Therefore I know I need to `join users on users.id = poster` , and ... `join contacts on contacts.id = users.main_contact` ?  But what would the whole query look like?

**Thank you, first answer.  I was able to take your example and form it into a query that will do what I need to do.**

```
SELECT announcements.*, contacts.name_first FROM announcements 
  LEFT JOIN users on users.id = announcements.poster
  LEFT JOIN contacts on contacts.id = users.main_contact
ORDER BY announcements.id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: What is with the Q down-votes - I don't get it?

Comment: i haven't voted, but I am guessing it looks a little bit like "will you do my homework for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly:

```
SELECT a.*, c.[name_first] 
FROM announcements a 
  LEFT JOIN users b on a.id = b.poster 
  LEFT JOIN contacts c on c.id = b.main_contact 
ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 3;
```